# Getting every tr class elements from html code

Tags: php

I build up this code:

```
    $url_athlete = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/athletes/tr/giangiorgio-count-trissino-1.html';
                  $html3 = file_get_html($url_athlete,true);

          $results = array();

                    foreach($html3->getElementsById('results') as $tag3){

                     foreach($tag3->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tag4){

                       echo $tag4->plaintext . "\n";

}
}
```

Thanks to this code, if I print out the tag4 variable getting this output:

```
Games   Age   City   Sport   Event   Team   NOC   Rank   Medal
    1900 Summer    22    Paris    Equestrianism    Mixed Long Jump    Italy    ITA    2    Silver
    1900 Summer    22    Paris    Equestrianism    Mixed High Jump    Italy    ITA    1T     Gold
    1900 Summer    22    Paris    Equestrianism    Mixed High Jump    Italy    ITA    4
```

Well, I tried in various ways with no results, I'd like to obtain this values from tag4 and assign them to  variables, i.e.:

```
$year --> 1900
$season --> Summer
$Sport --> Equestrianism
$gender -> Mixed
$event --> Long Jump
$rank --> 2
$medal --> silver
```

after this I will insert this values into a table.
Then the second row:

```
$year --> 1900
    $season --> Summer
    $Sport --> Equestrianism
    $gender -> Mixed
    $event --> High Jump
    $rank --> 1T
    $medal --> gold
```

then insert, and so on for last row.
How could I do?

Comment: Hint: Inside TR there are TD tags. Consider looping through them as well.

Comment: I tried but I get a loop cycle